# C# Nullable why is object.HasValue possible if object is null?

Tags: c#, nullable

why is the line:

```
Assert.IsFalse(myInt.HasValue);
```

possible? I would expect a `NullPointerException` as `myInt` is `null`.

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test_NullableInt_ShortDeclaration_WithValueAssignment()
    {
        int? myInt = null;

        Assert.IsNull(myInt);
        Assert.IsFalse(myInt.HasValue); // Why is this possible?

        myInt = 5;
        Assert.IsNotNull(myInt);
        Assert.IsTrue(myInt.HasValue);
    }
```

Regards

Comment: This is possible because `myInt` is not actually `null`. In fact, `int?` can never be `null` at all, because it's a value type (a `struct`). C# compiler applies special tricks to make `myInt` pretend it's `null` when it has no value.

Comment: `int?` is actually `Nullable<int>` which is a `struct` and while letting you represent empty/non-existent *values* it can't really be `null` at runtime.

Comment: [_Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)_](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/)